# When i import a world in minecraft, which a previously joined in multiplayer, how do I play as my multiplayer character rather than original creator?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend has a Minecraft Bedrock world which we played together. He exported it and I imported it, but I spawn as him. Can I somehow play as my character from our multiplayer sessions in that world?

Answer (score 1):

A dedicated server is need.

Download dedicated server here: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock/

Unzip and run `bedrock_server.exe` for a few seconds to generate the default world.
Open `server.properties` and set `online-mode=false` ( https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/minecraft-bedrock-support/2983414-authenticate-to-microsoft-services ).

Go into `./worlds/Bedrock level` delete the content and past in you world.

Allow UWP apps to connect to localhost: Run PowerShell as admin and execute `CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe"` (https://pmmp.readthedocs.io/en/rtfd/faq/connecting/win10localhostcantconnect.html)

Open Minecraft Bedrock and add server ip `127.0.0.1` por `19132` (you can see the ports when you launch the server).